# How can I generate all odd numbers less than N which are divisible by 5?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given a number $N$, how can I write down a summation of all odd numbers divisible by 5 which are also less than $N$?

For instance, if $N = 27$ then I am looking for a series to generate $5+15+25$.

Its pretty clear the series looks like

$$\sum_{k=0}^{???} 5(2k+1)$$

but I am having trouble with that upper index.  It must involve flooring to the nearest integer divisible by 5 (maybe write this as $\lfloor N \rfloor_5$ perhaps there is better notation).

Answer (score 3):

You want $5(2k+1) \le N < 5(2(k+1)+1)$, which means $k \le \frac{N/5-1}{2} < k+1$; now take floors.

Answer (score 1):

You want $5(2k+1) \leq N$. Thus
$$k \leq \frac{N}{10}-\frac{1}{2}.$$
Thus $k=\left\lfloor \frac{N}{10}-\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor$.

Answer (score 0):

We have to find the sum of all odd numbers less than N and divisible by 5

where N is given. For a given N you can find the number of odd numbers divisible

by 5 is $$\left[\frac{N}{5}\right]-\left[\frac{N}{10}\right]$$ So the reqired sum is equal to $$\sum_{i=1}^{\left[\frac{N}{5}\right]-\left[\frac{N}{10}\right]}\left(5+10(i-1)\right)$$.